# How to save authorization values of an API response in MVC Core 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, model-view-controller, sapb1

I am trying to establish a connection with SAP Business One Service Layer, but when trying to make requests it tells me that I do not have authorization.
When you perform in Postman everything goes well.

Login POSTMAN:

[image]

Here in the second image, it is seen how a cookie is automatically generated, which I think is what I lack in my MVC Core application.

Get POSTMAN:

[image]

When trying to do it in my project, the login if it runs correctly and I get the same answer

Login successful:

[image]

But when I do the GET to get the other information I get the following error.

Error GET:

[image]

This is my complete code:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A little note for the future**: please post your code in actual code blocks and not as images.

You may consider using the [HttpClientHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netcore-3.1) to manage cookies for you. This means when you make a request and the response has some [Set-Cookie headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie), the HttpClientHandler will automatically include those cookies in your next request:

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    var jsonString = @"{""CompanyDB"":""MICOMPANY""}";
    var postData = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var loginResponse = await client.PostAsync("https://some-site.com/loginPath", postData);

    // ...

    // This GET request will automatically include the cookies you received above
    var dataResponse = await client.GetAsync("https://some-site.com/give/me/data");
}
```

Comment: It's a great answer but how can I send the postData?

How is httpContext used?

Comment: @Magdaleno I added an example using `StringContent` to post your data/login credentials. Of course the `jsonString` should include all you need. I hope that's what you're asking for?

Comment: What do you mean by how `HttpContext` is used? The code you're writing here looks like a client-side application. `HttpContext` is only a term I know from ASP.Net's backend - what do you need it for?